# Como abrir uma imagem aleatoria

Tags: javascript, random, img

estou com uma nova duvida e este tem sido o melhor lugar para encontrar respostas, desde ja agradeco.
Meu problema e o seguinte, estou fazendo um questionario escolar para meu filho.
E uma coisa simples, ao menos deveria ser. Uma questao com 3 respostas, uma certa e duas erradas. Ao clicar na resposta certa uma imagem comemorativa aparece.
Gostaria que esta imagem fosse aleatoria para nao se tornar cansativa.
Estou usando o seguinte

```
function SIM() {
    var oImg = document.createElement("img");
    oImg.setAttribute('src', 'img/certo.jpg');
    oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'na');
    oImg.setAttribute('height', '200px');
    oImg.setAttribute('width', '200px');
    document.body.appendChild(oImg);
}
```

E no body

```
<button id="SIM" onclick="SIM();">6</button>
```

Gostaria de ter 10 imagens de comemoracao e estava pensando em algo do tipo

```
function SIM() {  
    var oImg = document.createElement("img");  
    oImg.setAttribute('src', '**NUMERO DE 1~10 ALEATORIO**.jpg');  
    oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'na');  
    oImg.setAttribute('height', '200px');  
    oImg.setAttribute('width', '200px');  
    document.body.appendChild(oImg);  
}
```

Existe alguma maneira de conseguir isso???
Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criares um numero aleatorio podes fazer `Math.round(Math.random() * 10)`.

```
function SIM() {  
    var oImg = document.createElement("img");  
    var nr = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
    oImg.setAttribute('src', nr + '.jpg');  
    oImg.setAttribute('alt', 'na');  
    oImg.setAttribute('height', '200px');  
    oImg.setAttribute('width', '200px');  
    document.body.appendChild(oImg);  
}
```

Comment: Salvou Meu Dia, Muito Obrigado!!!  Nao sabia como chamar o resultado de uma var para dentro do atributo.